# how to prevent overlapping of labels of slider?

Tags: jquery, css

need help, I am using jquery-ui slider.
I have now:

[image]
and, must be:
[image]
Thanks for the help.

Method for update labels of handlers for  my slider plugin:

```
updateLabelsOfHandlers: function() {

            var scope = this.data('scope');
            this.find('#min').text(scope.params.minLoanAmount);
            this.find('#max').text(scope.params.maxLoanAmount);    
            this.find('div.sliderLabel-value').remove();

            if (scope.sliderValue.length === 0) {
                this.find('#slider a:eq(0)').hide();
            }

            for (i = 0; i < scope.sliderValue.length; i++) {
                var chield = this.find('#slider a:eq(' + i + ')');
                chield.html('<div class="sliderLabel-value">' + scope.sliderValue[i] + '</div>');
            }
            },
```

bit of slider structure:

```
$(this).append(
                        '<div class="sliderContainer">'+
                            '<div id="sliderInfo">'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '<div class="sliderColumn-center">'+
                                '<div id="slider"></div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '<div id="leftDiv" class="sliderColumn-left">'+
                                '<div id="min"></div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '<div class="sliderColumn-right">'+
                                '<div id="max"></div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>')
```

I also added implementation for my problem (is what I expected)

```
updateLabelsOfHandlers : function() {

                var scope = this.data('scope');
                this.find('#min').text(scope.params.minLoanAmount);
                this.find('#max').text(scope.params.maxLoanAmount);    
                this.find('div.sliderLabel-value').remove();
                var labelsPositions = [];

                if (scope.sliderValues.length === 0) {
                    this.find('#slider a:eq(0)').hide();
                }

                for (i = 0; i < scope.sliderValues.length; i++) {
                    var chield = this.find('#slider a:eq(' + i + ')');
                    chield.html('<span class="sliderLabel-value">' + scope.sliderValues[i] + '</span>');
                    var sliderLabel = chield.find('.sliderLabel-value');
                    labelsPositions.push({sliderLabel:sliderLabel,width:sliderLabel.width(), left:chield.position().left, height:sliderLabel.height()});
                }

                var bottomShift = labelsPositions.length > 0 ? parseInt(labelsPositions[0].sliderLabel.css('bottom')) : 0;

                for (i = 1; i < labelsPositions.length; i++) {
                    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {

                        var leftLabelBottom = parseInt(labelsPositions[j].sliderLabel.css('bottom'));
                        var rightLabelBottom = parseInt(labelsPositions[i].sliderLabel.css('bottom'));
                        var leftLabelSize = labelsPositions[j].left + labelsPositions[j].width;  
                        var rightLabelSize = labelsPositions[i].left;


                        if (leftLabelSize > rightLabelSize && leftLabelBottom === rightLabelBottom) {
                            bottomShift += labelsPositions[j].height;
                            labelsPositions[i].sliderLabel.css("bottom", bottomShift + 'px');
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: show us the code please!! diagram doesnt help much to solve the problem!

Comment: Don't mind but this looks like `css` issue!! Its better you create a fiddle for this!!

Comment: I don't know how make relative divs in this case =(

Comment: how about detecting if the label touch then add a class to set one of them higher with css?

Comment: "detecting if the label touch " - can you give me this example if you have ?, please

Comment: you have the values of the sliders, if they are the same in terms of there min/max, or you can work out the ratio, then you can use the slider value to determine if the labels touch or not

Comment: As Guruprasad said please create a fiddle, I'm afraid I can't help you otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put all label in array
2. Store each 'width' of your label
3. Sorting your data by time and check from start of video / player,
4. If your label 'B' is in the range of label 'A',then lift label 'B' up
5. if your label 'C' is in the range of label 'A' and label 'B', then lift label by up * (number in range)

in case for CSS you need to create class of Shift1, Shift2, Shift3, ... with different y position (I think you might need 6 at the most, otherwise no one can see the thing over your slider )

Comment: I added implementation